# Web.SiteLogoUrl breaks with special characters

Tags: sharepoint

When I set the CSS & Logo properties using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Web, the SiteLogoUrl breaks when special characters are used.  It gets UrlEncoded in Web.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

```
 web.AlternateCssUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/custom.css";
 web.SiteLogoUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/Nike_Swoosh_Logo_BK.png"; 
 web.Update();
 web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: Do update your question when you get to a solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using HttpUtility.UrlEncode to fix the encoding of it before you write the string?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx